# Except homepage redirect all URLS exactly (change domain)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I must to change domain from htpps://www.example.net to https://www.example.com.

I need to permanently redirect all URLS exactly except homepage.

This redirect all URLS exactly, but I need for the moment to not redirect homepage too:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule !^$` - match anything that is _not_ a request for the base URI?

Comment: Note what the [tag:apache] tag says about a proper place for httpd-configuration questions